# Import Raspberry Pi GPIO error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, raspberry-pi2

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 B and attempting the project on the following website:
https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-face-recognition-treasure-box/overview

However when I try to run the file "capture-positives.py", I get an error when trying to import the GPIO. I have tried updating the GPIO  and removing and installing a fresh copy, however I keep getting the same error. I have a feeling it has to do with me using a Raspberry Pi 2 rather than a 1. Is there anyway to solve this error?

Update:

Left out the error section by mistake
this is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "capture-positives.py", line 14, in <module>  import hardware  File "/home/pi/pi-facerec-box-master/hardware.py", line 8, in <module>  import RPIO  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/RPIO-0.10.0-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/RPIO/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>  import RPIO._GPIO as _GPIO  SystemError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!
```

Comment: Please post the actual error, not some vague description.

Comment: Try import RPi.GPIO as gpio

Comment: @peekaboo Did you ever come up with a solution to either hardware.py or something else?

Comment: @JeffB6688 As I can't really remember but i believe I did remove certain lines in the code that is redundant(related to the GPIO pins) as I did not need the GPIO pins for that particular project and it works. I believe. There nothing much I could do as the py file wasn't updated for raspberry pi 2 eventho it say it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script (or more precisely, the `hardware.py`-module) uses the RPIO module which has seen it's last release 2013 (https://github.com/metachris/RPIO), and thus doesn't support the RPi2. You can either

- create an issue in the RPIO-tracker, and hope for an updated version (not sure how likely that's going to happen though)
- rewrite the hardware.py to use the GPIO module instead, but that might be a lot of work

Comment: Alright thanks for your feedback. Any tips or tutorial you know that I could learn to modify the hardware.py ?

Comment: Nothing beyond the actual documentation of GPIO and the controlled hardware.